# use of apply in a function that accepts vector, matrix, or data.frame as an argument

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that accepts (amongst other things) an argument that might be either a `vector`, a `matrix`, or a `data.frame`.

```
set.seed(101)
MyT <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)
S   <- sample(seq(0, 1, 0.01), 15, replace = T)
L1  <- sample(c(0,1), 15, replace = T)
L2  <- sample(c(0,1), 15, replace = T)
M1  <- as.matrix(L1)
M2  <- as.matrix(L1, L2)
D1  <- data.frame(L1)
D2  <- data.frame(L1, L2)
```

I'd like to write a function that is generic enough to accept `L1` (or `L2`), `M1`, `M2`, `D1`, or `D2` as an argument, which I'll call `myArg`. Inside the function, I want to do something like:

```
sapply(MyT, function(t) { apply(D2[S > t, ], 2, sum) })
```

The line above works well. The issue is that I need to make it generic, like:

```
sapply(MyT, function(t) { apply(myArg[S > t, ], 2, sum) })
```

However, this code would fail, for instance, if `myArg` is `L1` or `L2`. In this particular case, because I am trying to subset a vector illegally, the error message will read `incorrect number of dimensions`. If I fix the subset issue, then I run into the `dim(X) must have a positive length` issue, because I can't use `apply` on a vector. And so on and so forth...

So, I've landed on trying to do the following:

```
sapply( MyT, function(t) { 
  if (length(dim(myArg)) == 0) sum(myArg[S > t])  # for vector
  else if (dim(myArg)[2] == 1) sum(myArg[S > t, ])  # for single-column matrix or data.frame
  else sapply(myArg[S > t, ], 2, sum)  # for multi-column matrix or data.frame
})
```

I expected this to work, but I'm still getting the `Error in apply(myArg[S > t, ], 2, sum) : dim(X) must have a positive length` when I use `M2` as `myArg`.

I'm confused because `dim(M2)` yields `[1] 15  2`.

Curious if anyone can shed light on why I get this error when I use `M2` as `myArg`

Comment: I'd use `is.vector`, `is.matrix`, and `is.data.frame` to test. You may want to account for arrays, as well. You could also make separate methods for the function, which is probably the right way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

R has an object framework. It has three of them, in fact (four if you count R6, five if you count proto). So why not make use of them?

```
myFunc <- function(x, ...)
UseMethod("myFunc")

# don't use apply() on data frames unless you know what you're doing
myFunc.data.frame <- function(x, S, t, ...)
sapply(x[S > t, ], myFunc.default)

myFunc.matrix <- function(x, S, t, ...)
apply(x[S > t, ], 2, myFunc.default)

myFunc.default <- function(x, S=1, t=0, ...)
sum(x[S > t])
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I tried this, and still got the `Error in apply(x[S > t, ], 2, myFunc.default) : dim(X) must have a positive length` message. (EDIT: the call I made was `myFunc.matrix(M2, S, MyT)`)